# Godot Export for Nintendo 3DS?

Tags: export, homebrew, godot, gdscript, nintendo-3ds

I am making a game with the Godot Engine, and I am wondering if there is a way to make it so I can export it in a .cia or .3dx format so I can install it on a 3DS with Homebrew.

Comment: You need a modified version of Godot for this. There have been some projects on that regard. Try a web search.